# Can textures be rotated?

Tags: texturing, compositing-nodes

I'm using textures in the compositor. Is it possible to rotate these textures?

[image]

The rotate node doesn't work, due to cropping of the corners. What I actually need is to rotate the whole coordinate space.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried controlling it in the texture panel?

Comment: Yeah, but I don't think there's anything there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a rotated node texture and use it in the compositor. To be able to create a node texture, I needed one 3D object with a material and the texture assigned, though.

[image]

In the blend file the node texture is top left, then to the right the compositing nodes. In the compositor, you can switch between the viewer nodes with the rotated node texture (top viewer node) and a not rotated non-node texture (bottom viewer node) to see the effect.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Seems like the boundaries of the texture are determined by the render dimensions.  A work around is playing with the **Texture Scale** for the texture along with the **Scale** on a Transform node.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Of course, this stretches the texture, but it's a good work around. I'll accept it if nobody can come up with a way to do it without introducing distortion.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a more complete solution. It doesn't distort the base texture, and doesn't require any objects. Grab the "Rotated Texture" node tree from this file:

[image]

Here are the guts. The inputs are Scale (as in, the usual "scale" input for a texture node), the Angle you want to rotate the texture by, and the width and height of your render (I really hope this one becomes directly available as an input node in the compositor, but oh well). Unfortunately, you have to go into the group to change the base texture.

The ultimate "scaling factor" for the rotated texture is given by AR/(sin(theta)+cos(theta)), where AR is the aspect ratio of your canvas and theta is the angle you rotated the image by. In this node tree, the input angle first gets converted from degrees to radians ("2*arccosine(0)" outputs "pi"). At the same time, the input "Scale" to the texture node gets multiplied *up* by the aspect ratio (a larger "Scale" makes the features look *smaller*). The resulting texture image is then rotated by theta and scaled by AR/(sin(theta)+cos(theta)). The final output should look identical to a texture with the same inputs as the node group, only rotated.

Hope this helps!

[image: Node Tree for Rotated Texture node group]