# Rotated Gradient Blur in Compositor

Tags: compositing-nodes, depth-of-field

I have a rendered image (actually sequence of images) and want to 'fake' a depth of field in the compositor by using a blur, or a defocus. My preconceived notion was that I should produce a gradient texture and use either the blur node and a color mix to combine the unblurred and blurred versions according to a factor prescribed by the gradient texture, or use a defocus node with the Z factor prescribed by the gradient. However, this seems much harder than it should be for the following reasons:

- Creating a texture for the compositor seems hard - the only way I could find to do it was switching off Cycles and into BI, creating a new texture, and then switching back.
- When using a Blend texture in the defocus node, it seems very hard not to get a sharp 'edge' where the blur 'turns on'.
- Most confusingly, it seems impossible to rotate a texture in the compositor. In the node editor for a material, this is trivial, but I can't see how to do it here.

Any advice regarding the above confusion, or on a better way to achieve my goal, would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Use a mask instead ;-)

Comment: To rotate, connect the texure to a [rotate](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/types/distort/rotate.html) or [transform](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/types/distort/transform.html) node

Comment: @sambler Both of those methods end up clipping the texture to the dimensions of the image. Again, this is different to behaviour for material node. See here: https://imgur.com/a/2FINzvG

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a gradient you can build a mask really quickly. Use the shift drag function to extrude a feathered edge from the shape. Invert the color of the mask using the little invert icon in the mask window.

[image: defocus using a mask]

Comment: Thank you. I will give that a try. It would (as always) be nice if there was a procedural way to do this.

Comment: Well you can use the distort>lens distortion node, leave it in white, you'll get a fitted circle (circle edges touch all sides of the pros dimensions). Then apply a blur.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use the distort>lens distortion node, leave it in white, you'll get a fitted circle (circle edges touch all sides of the pros dimensions). Then apply a blur.

[image: distort node]

Or for a perfect circle use a Bokeh Shape node with Rounding turned up to 1.000. Add a Scale node set to Fit, then blur or use Dilate/erode node set to feather

[image: bokeh circle]

And you can make variations of gradients using the texture Marble (in cycles or Blender internal), here I have made a rectangle that you can scale with the Less Than node.

[image: marble square]

Using this basic Marble texture

[image: marble simple lines]

Answer (score 0):

As far as rotating a texture in the compositor goes, you can use the "Rotated Texture" node group from this file:

[image]

Explanation here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/131433/68997.